# Input from file in C, data types

Tags: c, input, types

thanks in advance for taking the time to read through my question...

```
/* Binary search for use with Gen_window.comp */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char line[1000];
  double sig, E;

  FILE *fp, *fopen();
  fp = fopen("sig_data", "r");

  if (fp==NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!");
  }
  else {
        printf("Processing file...");
  }



  while( (fgets(line, 25, fp) != NULL) ){
        fscanf(fp, "%lf\t%lf", &E, &sig);
        printf("\nThe energy is: %lf eV\nThe corresponding cross section is: %lf barns\n",E, sig);
  }

}
```

Numbers in the file are of the format X.XXXXXX+X or X.XXXXXX-X accordingly.  Does C have a way to specify this as input?  Is it a bother that there is no 'e'.  I cannot find any documentation that tells about inputing exponential, only returning exponential...

I do not need it to print that exact format, any other exponential format would be fine.

I realize there should be some specifiers and precision in my %lf, or maybe it should be %e, but I have tried everything that makes sense to me, so I am basically leaving it blank.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jester and plinth's answers are broadly correct, but flawed.  There is indeed no way to make the stock number-parsing routines (`*scanf`, `atof`, `strtod`) process a number in the format you have.  However, the suggested workarounds are bad.  First off, it is my personal opinion that `*scanf` and `ato*` should never be used, due to their horrifically bad handling of malformed input. More seriously, decimal-to-float conversion requires extended-precision arithmetic to avoid loss of accuracy.  `strtod` (which is the routine that *should* be used for this problem) can be relied on to do this correctly, but processing the mantissa and exponent separately and then combining them in the obvious fashion does *not*.  You need an intermediate type bigger than `double` and you need powers of 10 that are accurately computed all the way to the last bit, which `pow` doesn't reliably give you.

So my recommendation is to rewrite each line on the fly to make it acceptable to `strtod`.

1. Read each line into a pair of string buffers, splitting at `\t`.  I would do this by hand, but you can *probably* get away with using `fscanf` as long as you only use `%s` formats.  Make sure that each buffer has at least two extra bytes of space available.
2. Scan each buffer for the `+` or `-`.  Use `memmove` to shift that and all subsequent bytes of the string down one.  Poke an `e` into the buffer at the original position of the sign.  (If you do step 1 by hand you can combine this step with the loop for that step.)
3. You now have the number in a format that `strtod` can process.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately C does require the "e". So you will have to parse the input for yourself. Such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double parse(const char** cursor)
{
    int len;
    double mantissa, exponent;
    char sign;
    sscanf(*cursor, " %lf%[+-]%lf%n", &mantissa, &sign, &exponent, &len);
    *cursor += len;
    return mantissa * pow(10, (sign == '-' ? -exponent : exponent));
}

int main()
{
  char line[1000];
  double sig, E;

  FILE *fp, *fopen();
  fp = fopen("sig_data", "r");

  if (fp==NULL){
        puts("Error opening file!");
        return 1;
  }
  puts("Processing file...");

  while( (fgets(line, 25, fp) != NULL) ){
        const char* cursor = line;
        E = parse(&cursor);
        sig = parse(&cursor);
        printf("The energy is: %e eV\nThe corresponding cross section is: %e barns\n",E, sig);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

(Add error handling as needed)

Comment: From the parsing function, in the sscanf statement, do you mean " ...%d\n" ?

Comment: Are you asking about the %n? That stores the number of characters processed. I use that to advance the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

fscanf won't help you if there are no exponents so you're on your own.  That means splitting the string at the +/-, calling atof() on the left, atoi() (or atof()) on the right and multiplying the first by the first to 10 raised to the second:

```
char *splitAt(char *s, char *stops)
{
   if (!s) return 0;
   char *t;
   for (t = s; *t && strchr(stops, *t) == NULL; t++)
       ;
   int len = t - s;
   t = malloc(len + 1);
   strncpy(t, s, len);
   t[len] = '\0';
   return t;
}


double parse_my_float(char *input)
{
    /* allocates a new string */
    char *mantissaStr = splitAt(input, "+-"); /* check for null! */
    double mantissa = atof(mantissaStr);
    int len = strlen(mantissaStr);
    free(mantissaStr);
    int exponent = atoi(input + len);
    return mantissa * pow(10, exponent);
}
```

Comment: I think, what you really want to say is, I should write a python script to put the input file in the proper format ;-)  Should it be something like X.XXXXXXe+XXX  ?

Comment: Maybe, I was assuming the input format is immutable or impractically mutable.

Comment: You are certainly right to assume that!  I was making a pass at C, which I very nearly loath, not making a pass at you!!  Sorry if I seemed snide...

Answer (score 0):

How about using strtok and strtod, it should do it for you quite nicely.  Using sscanf or fscanf very error prone.  See below:

```
const char* insertE(char* out, const char* src)
{
    char* p = out;
    while (*src) {
        if (*src == '+' || *src == '-') {
            *p++ = 'e';
        }
        *p++ = *src++;
    }
    return out;
}
.
.
.
char line[1000];
char tmp[100];
double sig, E;
FILE *fp;
char* end;

fp = fopen("sig_data", "r");
if (fp==NULL){
    printf("Error opening file!");
    return;
}
else {
    printf("Processing file..."); 
    while(! feof(fp) && (fgets(line, 1000, fp) != NULL) ) {            
        E = strtod(insertE(tmp, strtok(line, "\t")), &end);
        sig = strtod(insertE(tmp, strtok(NULL, "\t")), &end);
        printf("\nThe energy is: %lf eV\nThe corresponding cross section is: %lf barns\n", E, sig);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

This comes with a notice that this code assumes the input file is formatted exactly correctly.